# Seeing only the app version with Lumen POST API call

Tags: routes, lumen, lumen-5.2, lumen-5.3, lumen-routing

I am new to Lumen. I started using Lumen on MAC OS and running it inside a docker container.

The **app** service in the dockerfile is as follows:

```
app:
build:
  context: ./
  dockerfile: app.dockerfile
working_dir: /var/www
volumes:
  - ./:/var/www
environment:
  - "DB_PORT=3306"
  - "DB_HOST=database"
```

The mysql service is running perfectly as well. On opening http://localhost:9002 I can see the normal Lumen app versioning:

```
Lumen (5.4.6) (Laravel Components 5.4.*)
```

Now I have made an API end-point for simple sms to be acknowledged. The user should send from and to phone numbers and I just validate them against the data present in the db and return the result .

My **routes.php** reads:

```
$app->post('/outbound/sms', 'App\Http\Controllers\SmsController@sendSms');
```

My **SmsController** is present under App\Http\Controllers as well. It uses a PhoneNumber Model as below:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\PhoneNumber;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;

public function sendSms(Request $request)
{

        try
        {
            $fromModel = PhoneNumber::findOrFail($request->input('from'));
        }
        catch(ModelNotFoundException $e)
        {
            return response()->json(['message'=> '', 'error'=> 'from is not found']);
        }

        try
        {
            $toModel = PhoneNumber::findOrFail($request->input('to'));
        }
        catch(ModelNotFoundException $e)
        {
            return response()->json(['message'=> '', 'error'=> 'to is not found']);
        }

        $this->validateSms($_REQUEST);

        return response()->json(['message'=> 'inbound sms ok', 'error'=> '']);
}
```

My **.htaccess** file reads:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

</IfModule>
```

On making a POST API call from Postman ,

```
http://localhost:9002/outbound/sms?from=1234567890&to=3456789&text=hi
```

I always get the app version as the response:

```
Lumen (5.4.6) (Laravel Components 5.4.*)
```

Even appending index.php to the url doesn't work. 
Can't make out what's wrong?

**Update:**
Finally , I got routes working fine. My routes.php content should have been in routes/web.php instead of App\Http.

Nut now I am getting NotFoundHttpException. Below is the stack trace::

```
in RoutesRequests.php (line 594)
at Application->handleDispatcherResponse(array(0))

in RoutesRequests.php (line 532)
at Application->Laravel\Lumen\Concerns\{closure}()

in RoutesRequests.php (line 781)
at Application->sendThroughPipeline(array(), object(Closure))

in RoutesRequests.php (line 534)
at Application->dispatch(object(Request))

in RoutesRequests.php (line 475)
at Application->run(object(Request))

in index.php (line 29)
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally got the reason for that NotFoundHttpException:

Added the below lines in index.php:

```
$app = require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';

$request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture();

$app->run($request);
```

Solution as per the below link:

http://laravel-tricks.com/tricks/notfoundhttpexception-lumen.

For anyone who stumbles upon this question , please make sure to keep your routes in **/routes/web.php**.

Answer (score 0):

I came across same situation, in order to use the Lumen for REST API, Moving the routes from App/routes.php to routes/web.php worked for me. It did not require me to change the index.php.